# CakePHP runs unnecessary queries when retrieving related models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

The Event model has following relations:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',

    ),
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
    );
```

here is how I list the events depending on the user input:

```
$conditions = array('user_id'=>$id, 'date >=' => $from, 'date <=' => $to);
$events = $this->find('all', array(
                                'conditions'=>$conditions, 'order' => array('Event.date' => 'asc')));
```

And here are the 3 queries that are being run:

```
1   SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`surname` FROM `scheduling`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `company_id` = 1

2   SELECT `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`name` FROM `scheduling`.`projects` AS `Project` LEFT JOIN `scheduling`.`customers` AS `Customer` ON (`Project`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`) WHERE `Project`.`company_id` = 1

3   SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`project_id`, `Event`.`user_id`, `Event`.`date`, `Event`.`hours`, `Event`.`minutes`, `Event`.`xhours`, `Event`.`xminutes`, `Event`.`xdetails`, `Event`.`assignment`, `Event`.`start_time`, `Event`.`material`, `Event`.`meter_drive`, `Event`.`time_drive`, `Event`.`start_location`, `Event`.`finish_time`, `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`name`, `Project`.`customer_id`, `Project`.`project_nr`, `Project`.`address`, `Project`.`post_nr`, `Project`.`city`, `Project`.`company_id`, `Project`.`color`, `Project`.`start_date`, `Project`.`finish_date`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`employee_nr`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`surname`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`phone`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`post_nr`, `User`.`city`, `User`.`token_hash`, `User`.`company_id`, `User`.`car_id`, `User`.`image` FROM `scheduling`.`events` AS `Event` LEFT JOIN `scheduling`.`projects` AS `Project` ON (`Event`.`project_id` = `Project`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `scheduling`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Event`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `project_id` = 5 AND `date` >= '2013-07-01' AND `date` <= '2013-12-06' ORDER BY `Event`.`date` asc
```

In fact, I only need the third query and not the first two. What causes them and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

By default, CakePHP will try attach associations.

In all 3 models add:

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

This will allow you to "contain" your queries to specific models.

Now you can do you query thus:

```
$events = $this->find('all', array(
                            'conditions'=>$conditions, 
                            'order' => array('Event.date' => 'asc'),
                            'contain' => true));
```

Say you did want Users (but not Projects) back you can do:

```
$events = $this->find('all', array(
                            'conditions'=>$conditions, 
                            'order' => array('Event.date' => 'asc'),
                            'contain' => array('User')));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
$events = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>$conditions, 
    'order' => array('Event.date' => 'asc'),
    'recursive' => -1
));
```

recursive based on the max containment depth

Comment: But this way it only returns the events itself. The 3rd query gets as short as the events table, it does not return the fields from project.

Comment: In that case you can use containable behavior.

`$events = $this->find('all', array(
 'conditions'=>$conditions, 
 'order' => array('Event.date' => 'asc'),
 'contain' => array(
  'Project' => array(
   'fields' => 'Array of fields you want to get'
  )
 )
));`

Answer (score 1):

### Other code is responsible

This code:

```
$conditions = array('user_id'=>$id, 'date >=' => $from, 'date <=' => $to);
$events = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>$conditions, 
    'order' => array('Event.date' => 'asc')
));
```

Is responsible for this query:

```
SELECT 
    `Event`.`id`, 
    ...
FROM 
    `scheduling`.`events` AS `Event` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `scheduling`.`projects` AS `Project` ON (`Event`.`project_id` = `Project`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN 
    `scheduling`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Event`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE 
    `user_id` = 1 AND 
    `project_id` = 5 AND 
    `date` >= '2013-07-01' AND 
    `date` <= '2013-12-06' 
ORDER BY 
    `Event`.`date` asc
```

However there are only `user_id` and `date` conditions in the code in the question.

This condition:

```
`project_id` = 5
```

Is being added by un-shown code - probably a behavior. Check your code for where the `project_id` condition is defined, there is the answer.

### query #1 is unrelated

The first query does not look to be related to the code in the question at all - there is nothing in the question that requires finding a user's data. To find where that's coming from - you can use a simple technique. Open up the user model and put this in it:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function beforeFind() {
        debug(Debugger::trace());
        debug(func_get_args());
        die;
    }

}
```

This will give a stack trace of how the query is being triggered - edit the application code appropriately once you know where it comes from.

### query #2 is required

Assuming the query you want is actually correct (find all events for a single project) - there needs to be a way to restrict on project id. If that's not specified explicitly, the second query is looking for a project id by client id - i.e. the query you want depends upon that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conditions = array('user_id'=>$id, 'date >=' => $from, 'date <=' => $to);
$events = $this->find('all', array('recursive'=>0,
     'conditions'=>$conditions, 'order' => array('Event.date' => 'asc')));
```

the change in here is the recursive

recursive=>-1      mean will fetch only event

recursive=>0       mean will fetch event + to whom it belongs to, in this case project and user